# Subdivide Quadtree without the new operator

Tags: c++, memory-management, quadtree

In every implementation of Quadtrees I've seen, the subdivision method always uses the `new` operator to create the child cells.

Is there a way to avoid that? 
Because I recreate my Quadtree every frame to update it easily, but using `new` and `delete` about 200 ~ 300 times per frame is going to kill my performance.

This is my Implementation :

```
void UQuadtree::subdivide(Quad * Node)
{
    float HalfExtent = Node->Extent/2;
    FVector2D Center = Node->Center;

    Node->NW = new Quad(FVector2D(Center.X + HalfExtent, Center.Y - HalfExtent), HalfExtent);
    Node->NE = new Quad(FVector2D(Center.X + HalfExtent, Center.Y + HalfExtent), HalfExtent);
    Node->SW = new Quad(FVector2D(Center.X - HalfExtent, Center.Y - HalfExtent), HalfExtent);
    Node->SE = new Quad(FVector2D(Center.X - HalfExtent, Center.Y + HalfExtent), HalfExtent);
}

bool UQuadtree::insert(FVector2D* point, Quad * Node)
{
    if (!ConstructBox2D(Node->Center, Node->Extent).IsInside(*point)) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (Node->Points.Num() < Capacity) {
        Node->Points.Add(point);

        return true;
    }
    if (Node->NW == nullptr) {
        subdivide(Node);
    }
    if (insert(point, Node->NW)) { return true; }
    if (insert(point, Node->NE)) { return true; }
    if (insert(point, Node->SW)) { return true; }
    if (insert(point, Node->SE)) { return true; }

    return false;
}
```

And I do this for every points I want to add to my Quadtree (about 1000), every frames, after deleting the whole tree with the clear() function.

```
void UQuadtree::clear() {

    if (root->NW != nullptr) {
        delete root->NW;
        root->NW = nullptr;
        delete root->NE;
        root->NE = nullptr;
        delete root->SW;
        root->SW = nullptr;
        delete root->SE;
        root->SE = nullptr;
    }
}
```

(BTW,I implemented it in UE4).

Comment: Please give us the concrete implementation. Otherwise you will not get any concrete answer. Nevertheless, you can think about overloading `new` in order to create a memory pool.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
I've updated my post with more info on my implementation.

Comment: Instead of new/delete, why don't you try to put unused nodes into a free list and use a node from the free list unless none is available?

Comment: _"`new` and `delete` about 200 ~ 300 times per frame is going to kill my performance"_, did you actually benchmark that?

Comment: @wilx when you say "try to put unused nodes into a freelist" what do you mean by "unused nodes"? 
Does it mean I could create all the nodes in advance and pop them from the list when I subdivide the tree?

Comment: @PasserBy I tried it in UE4 and I barely get 60FPS (around 56~59), and I don't have lgihts, meshes, textures yet. Just the Quadtree. So I think it won't be viable.

Comment: You have no evidence that `new` is the culprit here, and as a working hypothesis it is rather dubious. You need to profile your code and identify tue actual bottlenecks. In any case, not recreating the entire tree every frame would probably be a good idea.

Comment: @n.m. You are right. I might step back and profile it to see where it's actually blocking.
 I must have read too much about the subject these days, I saw all kind of warning about memory allocation etc... That made me think that my approach was definitely bad.

Comment: To prevent individual allocations, you could provide chunks of pre-allocated nodes which are not yet in use. When nodes are sub-divided they can be taken out of that pool. (If sub-division is reversed they could be given back - this is how I understood @wilx.) If pre-allocated nodes are fully consumed and more are needed then a new chunk has to be allocated. This would at least reduce the number of individual allocations and might even improve the performance by better cache-locality...

Comment: @Scheff oh okay I see it now! Tanks for clarifying. 
I need to learn more about memory pool, but I'm already getting the core idea.

Comment: A memory pool could be in simplest case a list of vectors of nodes + a bit fiddling to manage unused vs. used nodes based on that pool. Please, be aware, while a vector provides convenient allocation by giving it an initial size - resizing it may invalidate all of its contents. (Therefore, I mentioned a list of vectors.) The "+ a bit fiddling to manage unused vs. used nodes" could become a bit more complicated if you want to give back individual nodes. Otherwise, some kind of counter is probably sufficient to recognize when a vector is exhausted (and a new one is needed).

Comment: @Scheff If I understand, I'd have some vector<Node> that reserve, let's say, a hundred bytes by default. 
When it gets oversized (just before), Instead of resizing it, I create a new one to store the new nodes. Actually instead of creating a new vector I simply create a list of them, and that represent my memory pool?

Therefore, when I want to subdivide my tree, instead of saying 
`Node* newNode = new Node();`
It would be something like this :
`Node* newNode = &Nodes.emplace();`
is that correct?

Comment: For a list of nodes, you had to allocate each instance individually. In a vector of nodes, you could allocate an "arbitrary" number of instances at once (which additionally are stored consecutively -> cache locality). If you address those nodes in the vector by pointer, you must prevent any reallocation (or addresses of contained nodes might become invalid). However, you have to limit the size of the vector and you may not know how much nodes will be required at maximum, or there usually will not be required as many as theoretically possible. Hence, the list of such vectors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187191/discussion-between-maxime-parata-and-scheff).

Comment: Sorry, I missed your invitation. However, I prepared a small demo and am about to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to demonstrate a very simple memory pool. (In my comment, I recommended a list of vectors for this, and this is what I want to elaborate below.)

At first, I make some constraints which are used to simplify the concept:

1. Nodes provide a default constructor.
2. No inplace construction of nodes is required.
3. Nodes are created consecutively and freed all at once.

So, I start with a `template class PoolT`:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename ELEMENT, size_t N = 16>
class PoolT {
  private:
    typedef std::list<std::vector<ELEMENT> > Data;
    Data _data;
    typename Data::iterator _iterEnd;
    size_t _n;
    size_t _size, _capacity;

  public:
    PoolT():
      _data(), _iterEnd(_data.end()), _n(N),
      _size(0), _capacity(0)
    {
      std::cout << "  PoolT<ELEMENT>::PoolT()\n";
    }
    ~PoolT() = default;

    PoolT(const PoolT&) = delete;
    PoolT& operator=(const PoolT&) = delete;

    ELEMENT& getNew()
    {
      if (_n >= N && _iterEnd != _data.end()) {
        _n = 0; ++_iterEnd;
        std::cout << "  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): switching to next chunk.\n";
      }
      if (_iterEnd == _data.end()) {
        std::cout << "  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): Chunks exhausted. Allocating new chunk of size " << N << ".\n";
        _iterEnd = _data.insert(_iterEnd, std::vector<ELEMENT>(N));
        _capacity += N;
        _n = 0;
      }
      std::cout << "  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT " << _n << " of current chunk.\n";
      return (*_iterEnd)[++_size, _n++];
    }

    void reset()
    {
      _size = _n = 0; _iterEnd = _data.begin();
    }

    size_t size() const { return _size; }
    size_t capacity() const { return _capacity; }
};
```

The chunks are implemented as `std::vector<ELEMENT>` and the list of chunks is just a `std::list<std::vector<ELEMENT>>`.

The `ELEMENT& getNew()` is the function to request a new ELEMENT from pool.

If the current chunk is exhausted, a switch to next chunk is performed.

If it was the last chunk then a new chunk is allocated and added to list.

Afterwards, the next element is returned from chunk.

Please, note, that I disabled copy constructor and copy assignment operator of `PoolT`. I don't see any sense in copying a memory pool. So, if it is done accidentally (e.g. forget to insert the `&` when intending to pass it by reference as argument to function) this will cause a compiler error.

For the elements, I made a `struct Node` which resembles parts of OPs quadtree node:

```
struct Node {
  Node *pNW, *pNE, *pSW, *pSE;

  Node(): pNW(nullptr), pNE(nullptr), pSW(nullptr), pSE(nullptr) { }
  ~Node() = default;

  Node(const Node&) = delete;
  Node& operator=(const Node&) = delete;

  void clear()
  {
    pNW = pNE = pSW = pSE = nullptr;
  }
};
```

The returned `ELEMENT` might have been used before. Hence, it should be reset to an intitial state afterwards. To keep it simple, I just made a function `Node::clear()` which resets the instance to an initial state.

I disabled the copy constructor and copy assignment operator of `Node` as well. In my sample, `Node` instances refer to each other by pointers. Hence, a reallocation of their storage would have fatal consequences. (It would make node pointers dangling.) The memory pool `PoolT` is build with this in mind. (For an accidental reallocation in `std::vector`, at least one of them (copy constructor or assignment operator) would have been needed. Hence,  I would get a compiler error in this case.)

A memory pool for `Node`:

```
typedef PoolT<Node> NodePool;
```

And a small test suite, to show things in action:

```
Node* fill(NodePool &nodePool, int depth)
{
  Node *pNode = &nodePool.getNew();
  pNode->clear();
  if (--depth > 0) {
    pNode->pNW = fill(nodePool, depth);
    pNode->pNE = fill(nodePool, depth);
    pNode->pSW = fill(nodePool, depth);
    pNode->pSE = fill(nodePool, depth);
  }
  return pNode;
}

void print(std::ostream &out, const Node *pNode, int depth = 0)
{
  out << (const void*)pNode << '\n';
  if (!pNode) return;
  ++depth;
  if (pNode->pNW) {
    out << std::setw(2 * depth) << "" << "pNW: "; print(out, pNode->pNW, depth);
  }
  if (pNode->pNE) {
    out << std::setw(2 * depth) << "" << "pNE: "; print(out, pNode->pNE, depth);
  }
  if (pNode->pSW) {
    out << std::setw(2 * depth) << "" << "pSW: "; print(out, pNode->pSW, depth);
  }
  if (pNode->pSE) {
    out << std::setw(2 * depth) << "" << "pSE: "; print(out, pNode->pSE, depth);
  }
}

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__

int main()
{
  DEBUG(NodePool nodePool);
  std::cout
    << "nodePool.capacity(): " << nodePool.capacity() << ", "
    << "nodePool.size(): " << nodePool.size() << '\n';
  DEBUG(Node *pRoot = nullptr);
  DEBUG(pRoot = fill(nodePool, 2));
  DEBUG(std::cout << "pRoot: "; print(std::cout, pRoot));
  std::cout
    << "nodePool.capacity(): " << nodePool.capacity() << ", "
    << "nodePool.size(): " << nodePool.size() << '\n';
  DEBUG(pRoot = nullptr);
  DEBUG(nodePool.reset());
  std::cout
    << "nodePool.capacity(): " << nodePool.capacity() << ", "
    << "nodePool.size(): " << nodePool.size() << '\n';
  DEBUG(pRoot = fill(nodePool, 3));
  DEBUG(std::cout << "pRoot: "; print(std::cout, pRoot));
  std::cout
    << "nodePool.capacity(): " << nodePool.capacity() << ", "
    << "nodePool.size(): " << nodePool.size() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested:

```
NodePool nodePool;
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::PoolT()
nodePool.capacity(): 0, nodePool.size(): 0
Node *pRoot = nullptr;
pRoot = fill(nodePool, 2);
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): Chunks exhausted. Allocating new chunk of size 16.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 0 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 1 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 2 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 3 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 4 of current chunk.
std::cout << "pRoot: "; print(std::cout, pRoot);
pRoot: 0xcb4c30
  pNW: 0xcb4c50
  pNE: 0xcb4c70
  pSW: 0xcb4c90
  pSE: 0xcb4cb0
nodePool.capacity(): 16, nodePool.size(): 5
pRoot = nullptr;
nodePool.reset();
nodePool.capacity(): 16, nodePool.size(): 0
pRoot = fill(nodePool, 3);
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 0 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 1 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 2 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 3 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 4 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 5 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 6 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 7 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 8 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 9 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 10 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 11 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 12 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 13 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 14 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 15 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): switching to next chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): Chunks exhausted. Allocating new chunk of size 16.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 0 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 1 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 2 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 3 of current chunk.
  PoolT<ELEMENT>::getNew(): returning ELEMENT 4 of current chunk.
std::cout << "pRoot: "; print(std::cout, pRoot);
pRoot: 0xcb4c30
  pNW: 0xcb4c50
    pNW: 0xcb4c70
    pNE: 0xcb4c90
    pSW: 0xcb4cb0
    pSE: 0xcb4cd0
  pNE: 0xcb4cf0
    pNW: 0xcb4d10
    pNE: 0xcb4d30
    pSW: 0xcb4d50
    pSE: 0xcb4d70
  pSW: 0xcb4d90
    pNW: 0xcb4db0
    pNE: 0xcb4dd0
    pSW: 0xcb4df0
    pSE: 0xcb4e10
  pSE: 0xcb4e70
    pNW: 0xcb4e90
    pNE: 0xcb4eb0
    pSW: 0xcb4ed0
    pSE: 0xcb4ef0
nodePool.capacity(): 32, nodePool.size(): 21
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed72766cedfe3a26)</kbd>

I used a rather small `N = 16` as default chunk size. I did this to show exhausting of chunks without the necessity to blow the samples size too much. For “productive” usage, I would, of course, recommend a higher value.

There is, of course, a lot of potential to make this more sophisticated, obtaining the C++ features like overloaded `new` and `delete`, in-place construction (like e.g. in [std::vector::emplace()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace)) or other exciting things.

Comment: This is exciting indeed! Thank you very much for taking your time to make this demo, I think it'll make a useful resource.

I'm quite new to C++, it's only been 2 month that I'm using it, so it takes me a little while before I understand new concepts. But this is so clear. 
I need to read it through again and try to get it done by myself, so I can assimilate it.

I was reading about overloaded `new` today, it seems very cool to use. 
Idk what in-place construction is but I'll read about it later. If you have other cool things like this to lead me to, I'll be glad to read about it!

Comment: @MaximeParata You are welcome. I inserted some additional notes about deleted copy constructors etc. and found a link for in-place construction.

Comment: I tried to implement the pool myself, but I don't get the return statement of the `GetNew()` function. What does `(*_ItrEnd)[++size, n++];` mean exactly?
usually the operator [x, y] is used for 2D arrays right? But here, even though we have a sort of 2D array, the operator [] is not supposed to work with lists. I understand that it's actually returning what's at `*_ItrEnd[n++]` But the whole statement is unclear to me. can you tell me how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @MaximeParata No. There are no 2D subscript operators in C++. `(*_iterEnd)` refers to current element in list. That's a `vector`. `[_n++]` retrieves the `_n`th element of it while `_n` is incremented afterwards. The result is `Element&` and that's what is returned. The `++_size` is an intended side-effect which I put into the expression for subscript with a sequence operator `,`. The result of `++_size` is discarded but the effect (the incr. of `_size`) happens immediately before returning the result of `[_n]`, and that's what I wanted. But, `++_size; return (*_iterEnd)[_n++];` works as well.

Comment: Okay I understand it better now. It's very neat and well simplified, I didn't even know that was possible. Thanks.